# SCCM 2012 collection path lookup

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sccm

I have a vb.net (2015) application that performs various SCCM functions.  One of these functions is a collection lookup.  So it does a recursive search and displays the path using the SMS_CollectToSubCollect WMI class.

We have recently migrated to SCCM 2012 and this function no longer works because 2012 uses folders not sub collections.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this function in SCCM 2012?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this thread whilst searching for a solution for my own C# application where I need to display the full path of the User/Device Collection folders inside SCCM Console. It seems I couldn't find any direct answers or solutions specifically for C# so I decided to share my own solution here for anyone who may be in a similar position. This code was tested succesfully in Visual Studio 2017.

For whoever is interested in displaying full collection folder paths in C# applications (possibly easily converted to vb):

I took this PowerShell script from [Peter van der Woude](https://www.petervanderwoude.nl/post/get-the-folder-location-of-an-object-in-configmgr-2012-via-powershell/)
and converted it to work in my C# application to fill listboxes with the full path to the collection folders. This uses recursion to find the full folderpaths, no matter how many levels deep the subfolder lies.

To retrieve the Collection items inside the folders you could use "SMS_ObjectContainerItem"

Please note: if you want to display the 'User' collection folders, change ObjectType to '5001', '5000' is Device Collections. 
Also, the connection to the SCCM server is handled elsewhere, so be sure to replace 'sccmConnection' with your own connection.

You will need to add a reference to AdminUI.WqlQueryEngine.dll file found in SCCM SDK.

It could probably be simplified further, but for this example I've used the code below. Feel free to use/modify/simplify:

```
using Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine;

   string ObjectFolder, ObjectParentFolder, ParentContainerNode;
            bool ParentFolder = false;
            int ParentContainerNodeID = 0;
         ListBox collectionLb, appLb;

 internal void RetrieveCollections(int ObjType)
    {
        string ContainerNode = "SELECT * FROM SMS_ObjectContainerNode WHERE ObjectType= " + "'" + ObjType + "'";

        WqlQueryResultsObject ContainerNodeResults = sccmConnection.QueryProcessor.ExecuteQuery(ContainerNode) as WqlQueryResultsObject;
        foreach (WqlResultObject NodeResult in ContainerNodeResults)
        {
            if (NodeResult != null)
            {
                ObjectParentFolder = NodeResult["Name"].StringValue;
                ObjectParentFolder = "\\" + ObjectParentFolder;
            }
            else
            {
                ObjectParentFolder = "Root";
            }

            if (NodeResult["ParentContainerNodeID"].IntegerValue == 0)
            {
                ParentFolder = false;
                collectionLb.Items.Add(ObjectParentFolder);
            }
            else
            {
                ParentFolder = true;
                this.ParentContainerNodeID = NodeResult["ParentContainerNodeID"].IntegerValue;
                ObjectFolder = NodeResult["Name"].StringValue;
                ObjectFolder = "\\" + ObjectFolder;
            }

            while (ParentFolder == true)
            {
                ParentContainerNode = "SELECT * FROM SMS_ObjectContainerNode " +
                                "WHERE ContainerNodeID = " + ParentContainerNodeID;
                WqlQueryResultsObject ParentContainerNodeResults = sccmConnection.QueryProcessor.ExecuteQuery(ParentContainerNode) as WqlQueryResultsObject;
                foreach (WqlResultObject ParentNodeResult in ParentContainerNodeResults)
                {

                    ObjectParentFolder = ParentNodeResult["Name"].StringValue;
                    ObjectParentFolder = "\\" + ObjectParentFolder;
                    string temp = ObjectParentFolder + ObjectFolder;

                    if (ParentNodeResult["ParentContainerNodeID"].IntegerValue == 0)
                    {    
                        ParentFolder = false;
                        collectionLb.Items.Add(temp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.ParentContainerNodeID = ParentNodeResult["ParentContainerNodeID"].IntegerValue;
                        ObjectFolder = temp;                           
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Result: \ROOTFOLDER\Subfolder(\Subfolder\Subfolder etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the collection structure is flat in SCCM 2012. Folders replaced collections as the organizational method.

I'm guessing you're looking for the folder path that a collection is nested in. For example:
Folder1
 |_ SubFolder1
      |_ SubFolder2
            |_ Collection 1

Here's a PowerShell script that may shed some light on what you need to do. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/SCCM-2012-Get-all-d14664df

In the PowerShell, note the query: Select * from SMS_ObjectContainerNode Where ContainerNodeID = '$ParentContainerID'

SMS_ObjectContainerNode is the object that represents the folder in the console. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc145264.aspx

If you have trouble maybe someone has some vb.net sample code, if not I can whip something up for you.

Comment: Yes, you know exactly where I am coming from.  The powershell script wont help for vb.net, but that query string may help.  Let me see what I can do, but if this is easy for you (not me) please share what you whip up.

Comment: Emmanuel, I am having no luck building this function.  I want to pass a Collection ID, which will then display the folder path to that collection....Site --> Business Unit --> Collection Name.  Did you have any success?